# Estimating memory footprint and CPU usage for a C library

Tags: c, cpu-usage, static-linking, memory-footprint, static-allocation

I have a static library written in C, with no dynamic memory allocation.

Until now, the library has only been used in an application for regular i386 Linux, where CPU and memory was plentiful.

I now need to try building a version of the library for an embedded, real-time ARM9 system (provided by a 3rd party). Before that I have to give some rough estimates of memory footprint and CPU usage.

For memory footprint, I build a tiny application on my i386 machine, statically linking with my library, that exercises all the functions of my library. Is it roughly correct that checking the resident memory of this application will give me a ballpark estimate of my library's memory footprint? Is there a better way to measure it?

For estimating CPU usage, I'm at a loss. I can of course run the test application mentioned above, on my i386 system, but I don't know what metrics that'll give me (if any) that can translate into something relateable to the ARM system. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Compile and run it on a RaspberryPi and maybe use gprof on it?

Comment: Raspberry Pi uses ARM11 and undoubtedly a different system architecture, memory, etc. If you find it's no good on ARM11 then I suppose that's useful, but otherwise you've learned nothing about ARM9.

Comment: Please clarify your question. You say *"For memory footprint, I build a tiny application on my i386 machine..."*, but do you build **for** i386 or ARM9?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your memory estimate sounds pretty good to me, **as long as you compiled it for ARM9**. Actually, if you cross-compile the library without debug info, and you expect all the functions of the library to be used in the final application, then the file-size of the library is a pretty good ball-park estimate. The only way that wouldn't work is if you had a lot of zero-initialized global (or static) variables. Run-time memory allocation is a different matter, of course, but you've accounted for that already.

Size estimates based on x86 code may be within the same ball-park, but really shouldn't be trusted. Sizes do vary from compiler to compiler also, so try to match it if you can, but any recent ARM compiler is OK for a *rough* estimate.

As for CPU estimates, that's impossible to put a figure on without measuring it. It's a function of the architectural efficiency of the CPU, effectiveness of compiler optimizations, clock rate, memory speed, bus speed, cache size, cache pressure caused by other running tasks, etc., etc., etc.  There's just too many variables.

One thing you might be able to do is use big-O notation to say something about the performance of the algorithms on different input.

I'd probably just say "light", or "heavy". You probably have an idea which of those fits.

Comment: Are you saying that compiling library on not-ARM system would give reasonable estimation of how big the library is on ARM system? That doesn't sound right at all: Compiling with 2 different compilers for the same architecture can yield 2 completely different memory sizes. It's even worse when comparing to 2 different architectures.

Comment: No, of course I'm not saying that. That would be absurd. Why would you even think of that?

Comment: *"For memory footprint, I build a tiny application on my i386 machine"* and *"Your memory estimate sounds pretty good to me."*

Comment: You're right, I only *assumed* he meant he cross-compiled it. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: ams & @user694733 , many thanks for your input, it's greatly appreciated. Yes, I actually built the "estimation application" on my i386 machine, compiled for i386. I have no ARM board yet, I was asked for these estimates before we'd acquire anything. My theory was that the i386 binary would at least give me a ballpark figure about the footprint. I do have a lot of zero-initialized storage (basically a statically allocated database of sorts), so I'll go hunt for an ARM board.

Comment: Hmm, on a second thought, I can just emulate an ARM9 box with QEMU, no? Hurrah for learning new things!

Comment: Yep, install QEMU on Ubuntu, for example, and ARM binaries run on x86 seamlessly. Other distros might need you to run QEMU explicitly, without additional config.